# List based modular arithmetic in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a file to track my goals when reviewing material. Since the objective is to read one chapter a day, I want to display my progress based upon the start date. Since this is a cyclical review, it requires some form of modular arithmetic to properly account for restarting the list at the end of the previous completion. I can't wrap my head around a straightforward method to do this via excel formulas or VBA programming, and figured the gurus here would be helpful.

Sample table:

Current day of cycle: XXX

Book  #_of_Chapters

Book A 10

Book B 15

Book C 30

Book D 5

Total Chapters: 60

Today: Book YYY Chapter ZZZ

Expected result: If XXX is 40, YYY is Book C and ZZZ is Chapter 15 (40-10 for Book A and 15 for Book B). If XXX is 62, YYY is Book A (since we've restarted) and ZZZ is Chapter 2.

I don't currently have the VBA code I started on to add to this post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you keep track of how many chapters were in previous books. Here's the CSV of my setup:

> Current Day of cycle:,16,
>  ,,
>  Book,Chapters,Prev. Chapters
>   Book A,10,0
>  Book B,15,10
>  Book C,30,25
>  Book D,5,55

I used a formula for Prev. Chapters but you don't really have to if your list is really this short.

```
=SUM($B$4:$B4)-B4
```

Now you have all you need. You can break it into 3 formulas to make it easier to follow: (mine are in the range `E1:E3`)

```
=IF(MOD(B1,60)=0,60,MOD(B1,60))
=MATCH(E1,C4:C7)
="Book " & INDEX(A4:A7,E2) & " Chapter " & E1-INDEX(C4:C7,E2)
```

... or you can have one big formula:

```
="Book " & INDEX(A4:A7,MATCH(IF(MOD(B1,60)=0,60,MOD(B1,60)),C4:C7)) & " Chapter " & IF(MOD(B1,60)=0,60,MOD(B1,60))-INDEX(C4:C7,MATCH(IF(MOD(B1,60)=0,60,MOD(B1,60)),C4:C7))
```

If you want just the book name and chapter number, it'd be these:

```
=INDEX(A4:A7,E2)
=E1-INDEX(C4:C7,E2)
```

... or as standalones:

```
=INDEX(A4:A7,MATCH(IF(MOD(B1,60)=0,60,MOD(B1,60)),C4:C7))
=IF(MOD(B1,60)=0,60,MOD(B1,60))-INDEX(C4:C7,MATCH(IF(MOD(B1,60)=0,60,MOD(B1,60)),C4:C7))
```

---

For your final application, I'd suggest the following:

- Make the total number of chapters dynamic instead of the hard-coded 60 shown in my examples
- Format the final output to look like whatever you need
- Keep the formulas separated so you can troubleshoot if something goes crazy. Big formulas give nice results but are hard to fix.

Comment: No, the list isn't this short - there's over 500 chapters spread across multiple categories with dozens of books! This looks like something workable. I've never used the MOD() function like that before. Hopefully I'll get to incorporating this later today! Thanks!